# How can I visualize the coordinate system of my model?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to visualize my body fixed coordinate system. How can I do this or what do I need to add into my .sdf file to visualize such a coordinate system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16446/how-can-i-visualize-the-coordinate-system-of-my-model?/) by [NRottmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3368/nrottmann/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-06-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the gazebo client on the top menu click "View -> Link Frames". Since link frames may be inside geometry, it helps to do "View -> Transparent" as well. The link frames show as 3 perpendicular axes: blue is +Z, red is +X, yellow is +Y.

Here's a PR2 with transparency and link frames.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NRottmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3368/nrottmann/) on 2017-06-16**:
Is there a possibility to include this already in the model.sdf file. For the transparency I could just add

1

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-06-16**:
Never done it myself, but I think you could set the alpha term of `<ambient>` to 0.25 http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=material#material_ambient  I believe the order is red, green, blue, alpha, so `1.0 1.0 1.0 0.25" would be a translucent white.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-06-16**:
For adding the frames to SDF, you could copy the X, Y and Z visuals here to each link in your robot: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/42215f2019f5ae64fc8a0610ef804a0fc53b0740/worlds/lookat_demo.world?fileviewer=file-view-default#lookat_demo.world-22

**Comment by [NRottmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3368/nrottmann/) on 2017-06-20**:
Thanks a lot. It works for me!